# Error when running an assembly program with a simple jb conditional jump

Tags: assembly, emu8086

im trying to make a program for dividing two numbers in assembly. Each of them has to be less than 255. right now im working on the input validation part and for some reason my program crashes when I attempt to use a label. If someone can give me some pointers what im doing wrong i would appreciate it very much.

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data

 M2 DB "Enter a 3 digit number with it's sign before it ( either + or -)",10D,13D,"$"
 M3 DB "the DIVIDAND:","$"
 M4 DB 10D,13D,"now enter one digit number for the DIVISOR:","$"
 M5 DB 13D,"    THE QUTIONT IS " , "$"
 M6 DB 13D,"    THE REMAINDER IS ", "$"
 M7 db "Error, too large","$"    
 S DW "( - )","$"
 N Dw 0
 D DW 0   
 SIGN DW  ?
 RES  DB 10 DUP ('$')

.code         
start:

MOV AX,@DATA
MOV DS, AX


MOV AH,09H
MOV DX,OFFSET M2
INT 21H

MOV DX, OFFSET M3
MOV AH, 09H
INT 21H
;run this code now   


mov ah , 01h ;read one char from user   
INT 21H         
CMP AL ,'-'   
XOR AH,AH
MOV SIGN,AX      





mov ah , 01h ;read one char from user
int 21h      ;interrupt and run this code now
sub al,30h   ; to take the number as decimal number
xor ah,ah    ; makes ah 0
mov bx ,100  ;to read a third digit (most significat bit)
mul bx       ;multiply bx by value in ax
push ax      ; saves the fisrt digit in stack




;first digit is read

mov ah,01h
int 21h
sub al,30h
mov ah,00
mov bx, 10h
mul bx
mov dx,ax   ;to store the new value of ax to dx
pop ax      ;return the first value of ax to ax
add ax,dx   ;move sum of ax and dx to ax
push ax     ;2 digits in ax


; second digits added

mov ah,01h
int 21h
sub al,30h
mov ah,00
mov bx,1h
mul bx
mov dx,ax
pop ax
add ax,dx
push ax  ; 3 digits in ax
pop ax
mov N,Ax     

cmp n,255   

jb LessThan

LessThan:

mov dx,4





ret 









  end   start
```

Comment: So, if it takes the jump, it's going to go to the `LessThan` label.  However if it *doesn't* take the jump, it's just going to proceed to the next instruction.  Which is also `LessThan`.

Comment: True.... I honestly didnt know where else to put the label. Any suggestions ?

Comment: How about getting rid of LessThan and adding a label after the `ret` named `TooBig`?  You could put some error printing there.  You'd need to change your `jb` instruction, since you would want to do the jump if it was Greater.